# Database Update Trigger to prevent removing specific characters at the end of the word

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to have an Update Trigger that will let user update first part of the name but will will prevent the last part from being removed.

For example I have a column Srt_Name with **CAR_GID23232** entry.

User should not have possibility to remove '**_GID23232**' part.
Here's what I came to, but it doesn't work:

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT Srt_Name,Srt_Id               
FROM inserted
WHERE Srt_Name not like '%_GID'+CONVERT(varchar(max),Srt_GidNumer)
)

BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Make sure that name ends with _GIDXXXX pattern.', 16, 1)
END
```

Comment: can you please make your question more understanding with sample input and output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one :

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT Srt_Name,Srt_Id               
FROM inserted
WHERE Srt_Name not like '%[_]GID'+CONVERT(varchar(max),Srt_GidNumer
)
```

Comment: That works. Answer accepted. I was using wildcard instead of [_]. Thank you @Kaushik Thanki